# Algorithm to add implied parentheses in boolean expression

Tags: string, algorithm, parsing

I have a string such as "A and B or not C and D". The atoms are all simple uppercase letters A,B,C... and the operators are only { and, or, not }.  I would like to devise an algorithm that can add parentheses that are implied by the usual rules of precedence.

Can anyone think of a very simple way to do this? perhaps using Regex?

The desired output is "(A and B) or ((not C) and D)".

Comment: I don't see how regex would help you. I think you'll have to parse the expression into a tree and then traverse that tree

Comment: It would be simple to write a [Definite Clause Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) for this, if you're familiar with parsing.

Comment: Sounds like you don't trust the _rules of precedence_

Comment: How is `a and b and c` grouped? Are brackets added in this case anyway?

Comment: @sin it's not that I don't machines, but i want to make it explicit so that humans will not misunderstand it.

Comment: @CommuSoft no parentheses are necessary for A and B and C, because they would not affect the boolean value of the expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be as simple as this (Python code ahead):

```py
def popnext(stream, token):
    if stream[0:len(token)] == list(token):
        del stream[0:len(token)]
        return True
    return False

def parse_binary(stream, operator, nextfn):
    es = [nextfn(stream)]
    while popnext(stream, operator):
        es.append(nextfn(stream))
    return '(' + ' {} '.format(operator).join(es) + ')' if len(es) > 1 else es[0]

def parse_ors(stream):
    return parse_binary(stream, 'or', parse_ands)

def parse_ands(stream):
    return parse_binary(stream, 'and', parse_unary)

def parse_unary(stream):
    if popnext(stream, 'not'):
        return '(not {})'.format(parse_unary(stream))
    return parse_primary(stream)

def parse_primary(stream):
    if popnext(stream, '('):
        e = parse_ors(stream)
        popnext(stream, ')')
        return e
    return stream.pop(0)


def evaluate(expression):
    return parse_ors(list(expression.replace(' ', '')))[1:-1]

print evaluate('A and B or not C and D')
print evaluate('A and (B or not C) and D')
```

result:

```
(A and B) or ((not C) and D)
A and (B or (not C)) and D
```

Comment: thank you... but yes, there can be parentheses in the original.

Comment: @JohnHenckel It's not hard to adapt for it. Also changed to not generate unneeded parentheses on subsequent "ands"/"ors".

Answer (score 0):

A grammar for your these Strings might be defined by the following [production rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Production_rule_notation):

1. S → E
2. E → E`or`E
3. E → F
4. F → F`and`F
5. F → T
6. F  → `not`T
7. T → `A`
8. T → `B`
9. T → `C`
10. T → `D`

(Make rule 6 "**T** → not T"), if strings like `"not not D and not not not B"` shall be allowed, too.)

While this grammar is context free, it isn't [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#A_regular_grammar). I don't think a regular grammar for your strings exists, so regular expressions are not sufficient to match exactly these strings, and by extension also not to parse and transform (re-write) them correctly.

Comment: Perhaps not a single RE, but multiple steps? for example, I know that one rule should be "not A and" => "(not A) and" where A can be either a single letter, or a parenthetical group. So I could use RE do bottom-up collapse each parenthetical group into single letters. And after each step I could apply the rules, such as "not A and" => "(not A) and"..... I'm going to prototype it now.

Comment: AFAIK, regex are unable to recognize well formed (i.e., correctly nested) parenthetical groups, as those aren't a regular grammar, either. So doing the replacement in several steps won't help as long as you're still using only regular expressions. This doesn't mean that regular expressions cannot be part of a solution, only that they alone (even if they are several), aren't sufficient.